# A compound modifier with the word "increase"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm confused about creating a compound modifier with the word "increase (or increasing)."
For example, "Consider what UGC-increasing (or UGC-increase) options you can use to promote the event."
I want to say about the options that help to increase user-generated content.

Comment: I had to read that sentence a few times, and still don't quite understand it. What is the purpose? To increase user-generated content or to promote an event? "User-generated content" is already a compound phrase.

Comment: The purpose is to increase user-generated content.

Comment: It is such a mouthful I would not even try. "Consider what options you can use to increase user-generated content."

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is getting hung up on the entire sentence when the OP's actual question is a pretty clear point of grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage here is **UGC-increasing**, because when we use a noun form like an adjective, we use the present participle form.

For example,

- to sleep: infinitive
- The dog is *sleeping*: present participle in present progressive tense
- The *sleeping* dog: present participle used as an adjective

In your example the activities are *increasing UGC*, so they are *UGC-increasing activities*.

Comment: Yes, but in "the sleeping dog" it would be better to say that "sleeping", though used as a modifier, is not an adjective but a verb.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't do that.

You've got a good clear way to express the idea in idiomatic English:

> Consider what options help to increase user-generated content.